# How do hidden MMC patitions work?

Tags: partitioning, storage, sd-card

[This project](https://github.com/ignasurba/mmcblkNX) allows users to access hidden boot partitions on the eMMC of Nintendo Switch, using a commercial SD/MMC card reader chip, Realtek RTS5170.

How do these hidden partitions work? Can I create one on a regular SD card, or are they a hardware feature of a particular storage chip? Are they mapped to the same pool of LBA sectors as the main partition, or do they have their own "address space"? Is there any way to see them on Windows, or are they only implemented in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A discussion of these devices is found in the article
[eMMC (Linux)](https://developer.toradex.com/linux-bsp/how-to/boot/emmc-linux/).

Basically, the eMMC device is actually two devices in one, which do not
even use the same storage technology.

> The eMMC device has a boot area, which is seen as a different block
> device than the regular user area. It is a vendor-specific area that
> uses an underlying storage technology more reliable than the user
> area, for instance, SLC or pSLC instead of MLC.
>
> The default partitioning scheme of an eMMC-based Toradex module is as
> follows:
>
> eMMC boot area:
>
> - Raw partition - U-Boot bootloader and environment, Toradex factory configuration block.
> - Raw partition - RPMB area. RPMB stands for Replay Protected Memory Block. It can be used to store sensitive data such as authentication
>   keys or any other information that shouldn't be on regular storage for
>   security reasons. To use it, a key must be programmed into it once and
>   then provided when writing or reading.
>
> eMMC user area:
>
> - FAT32 partition - Kernel and device tree.
> - EXT-4 partition - Root file system.

Accessing the boot area requires a special IOCTL disk command, which is
not usually issued by the disk driver of the operating system,
so in effect is well hidden from ordinary user programs.